# why the node in k8s cluster cant be connected?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

i create a cluster by kind in my local env

why the ip list by node cant connected? like bottom

```
NAME                 STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE       KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
kind-control-plane   Ready    control-plane,master   22h   v1.21.1   172.18.0.2    <none>        Ubuntu 21.04   4.19.121-linuxkit   containerd://1.5.2
```

`ping 172.18.0.2` get `Request timeout`

i follow doc https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/getting-started/ and blocked in step `Verify external access`

"http://$GATEWAY_URL/productpage" is not a useful site for me

i meet this question so when i test istio in local,cant expose my service from pod inside

so , how can i complete the step??

Comment: `ip ro get 172.18.0.2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind runs each Kubernetes node in a separate Docker container.  The IP address you see is a Docker-internal address, but that's not directly accessible (unless you're calling from outside a container, on the same host, and it's a native-Linux host).

When you create the kind cluster you need to [configure it to publish ports from the node container](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/configuration/#extra-port-mappings).  For this to work you need to know the port number on the node that's being published; if it's a NodePort-type service, you need to know (or probably directly specify) the `nodePort:` value, for example.

The Istio documentation describes [looking up the ingress port](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/getting-started/#determining-the-ingress-ip-and-ports) but that's not too useful since you need to reinstall the cluster with that value.  Istio has several [installation profiles](https://github.com/istio/istio/tree/master/manifests/profiles).  It's very possible to [customize them](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/additional-setup/customize-installation/), including changing the Service port definitions; the [Gateway definition](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/istio.operator.v1alpha1/#GatewaySpec) is substantial but does allow explicitly setting the `nodePort` values.

So: first, pick a port, in the ordinary NodePort range (30000-32767); let's use 31380 (a number that appears in the documentation page you link to).

You need to configure kind to make that port visible:

```yaml
# kindconfig.yaml
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
- role: control-plane
  extraPortMappings:
  - containerPort: 31380 # actually the nodePort
    hostPort: 8000       # some available port on your host (can be 80)
```

Create the cluster

```sh
kind create cluster --config=kindconfig.yaml
```

Create an Istio configuration.  Note that you must copy [the entire list of ports](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/b25c7eb/manifests/profiles/demo.yaml#L25-L45).

```yaml
# istioconfig.yaml
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  components:
    ingressGateways:
      - name: istio-ingressgateway
        enabled: true
        k8s:
          service:
            ports:
            - port: 15021
              targetPort: 15021
              name: status-port
            - port: 80
              targetPort: 8080
              nodePort: 31380 # <-- add this
              name: http2
            # and copy the remaining ports from the reference config
```

Then, in the new kind cluster, install Istio using this setup

```
istioctl install --set profile=demo -f istioconfig.yaml
```

Once Istio fully comes up and you deploy the application, you should be able to access `http://localhost:8000` from the host system, where 8000 is the kind `hostPort:` setting we configured (if you picked port 80 there, you can leave off the port number).

The routing here is:

- `localhost` port 8000 from the host reaches a Docker port-forward;
- Docker forwards to port 31380 in the `kind-control-plane` container;
- Port 31380 is attached to a NodePort (actually LoadBalancer) `istio-ingressgateway` Service in the `istio-system` namespace;
- That forwards to port 8080 on the actual ingress Pod(s);
- The ingress gateway does URL-based routing to your application using normal Kubernetes and Istio intra-cluster networking.

Comment: im glad to follow your answer to retry my work , and im learn a lot from this answer! thank you very much~

Comment: i follow these step , but get ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE  from localhost:8080. why?

Comment: Does `kubectl get service -n istio-system istio-ingressgateway -o yaml` show the right `nodePort:` value?  Does `docker ps` on the host show the correct port-forward into the node container?  You should be able to trace the flow through the list at the end of the answer.